# Progress Dialog is not showing 2 times when Activity is launchMode="SingleTask"

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

Hello i am having an issue with ProgressDialog not displaying second time when Activity has `launchMode="SingleTask"`.

I have to have the Activity as SingleTask. the first time that i click the Button the dialog is displaying but when i close the activity and start it again and i click the button the `ProgressDialog` is not displaying again.

My code:

```
private class FakeTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>{
        private FakeCallBackListener mListener;
        FakeTask(FakeCallBackListener listener){
            mListener = listener;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
            mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage(mContext.getString(R.string.processing_data));
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            mProgressDialog.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
            if (!((Activity)mContext).isFinishing()){
                mProgressDialog.show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(params[0]);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

and when Button is clicked i just call this:

```
new FakeTask(listener).execute(delay);
```

In the Manifest in the specific `Activity` i have:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

Any suggestions? I know that since the Activity is not actually destroyed is passing context to a dead dialog. But how do i fix the dialog to display everytime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have issue with accessing `mContext`.

Why not pass it as a parameter to FakeTask constructor?

```
private FakeCallBackListener mListener;
private Context mContext;

FakeTask(Context context, FakeCallBackListener listener) {
    mContext = context;
    mListener = listener;
}
```